Getting error "GSI_LOGGER]: The given login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID." even though config is there
EDIT: I have just found that if I use popup as the behavior, it the  works. But if I use redirect it doesn't.
I have an in-development web app which uses Google Sign In for auth. The app was working fine in local development till the last few months, when the gsi based auth stopped working.
This is only happening for localhost based development and I believe started when the 3rd party cookie deprecation warnings started to show up.
Currently the GSI button shows the last logged userid properly. but when I click on it, i get to a blank page with oauth uri in the address bar and GSI_LOGGER]: The given login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID. in the console.
I believe that my oauth credentials are set up properly for localhost usage.
enter image description here
My server also set the Referrer policy as no referrer when downgrade.
enter image description here
For reference, this is how I am invoking the gsi button;

                google.accounts.id.initialize({
                    client_id: "my-client-id",
                    login_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/signin/google",
                    context: "signin",
                    ux_mode: "redirect",
                    // prompt_parent_id: 'loginControls',
                    auto_select: false,
                    state: window.location.pathname,
                });
                google.accounts.id.renderButton(
                    document.getElementById("loginControls"),
                    { 
                        type: window.innerWidth < 768 ? "icon" : "standard",
                        shape: window.innerWidth < 768 ? "circle" : "rectangular",
                        theme: "outline", 
                        size: "large",
                        locale: "en_US",
                    }
                    // customization attributes
                );

Again, this was working fine months ago.
Now I am unable to do any local development at all. Can someone help me figure out what is broken?
Note: I am doing local dev using cloudflare's wrangler. I have also tested on both Chrome and Edge and this issue is not browser specific.
I rechecked the oauth credentials and referrer policy.
